# PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND when opening URL

Tags: url, web-scraping, get

On AirBNB, If I navigate my web browser to a room listing like [this one](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/13579297?source_impression_id=p3_1605385505_GUf4p52QXlkBLF81&guests=1&adults=1), then open the dev tools console to find out which URL has the JSON string containing the data displayed in the listing.

Thru the dev console, I found that [this URL](https://www.airbnb.com/api/v3/PdpPlatformSections?operationName=PdpPlatformSections&locale=en&currency=USD&_cb=wd9kppl0amks&variables=%7B%22request%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%2213579297%22%2C%22layouts%22%3A%5B%22SIDEBAR%22%2C%22SINGLE_COLUMN%22%5D%2C%22pdpTypeOverride%22%3Anull%2C%22translateUgc%22%3Afalse%2C%22preview%22%3Afalse%2C%22bypassTargetings%22%3Afalse%2C%22displayExtensions%22%3Anull%2C%22adults%22%3A%221%22%2C%22children%22%3Anull%2C%22infants%22%3Anull%2C%22causeId%22%3Anull%2C%22disasterId%22%3Anull%2C%22priceDropSource%22%3Anull%2C%22promotionUuid%22%3Anull%2C%22selectedCancellationPolicyId%22%3Anull%2C%22forceBoostPriorityMessageType%22%3Anull%2C%22privateBooking%22%3Afalse%2C%22invitationClaimed%22%3Afalse%2C%22discountedGuestFeeVersion%22%3Anull%2C%22staysBookingMigrationEnabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22useNewSectionWrapperApi%22%3Afalse%2C%22previousStateCheckIn%22%3Anull%2C%22previousStateCheckOut%22%3Anull%2C%22federatedSearchId%22%3Anull%2C%22interactionType%22%3Anull%2C%22searchId%22%3Anull%2C%22sectionIds%22%3Anull%2C%22checkIn%22%3Anull%2C%22checkOut%22%3Anull%7D%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22ef9bc5e1b5f40f9e2c1c95da2b749cb3cb03d6bdbb69085832e20e3d1c4cac55%22%7D%7D) contains that information, which I could see in the console. Here are screenshots from the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpRfW.jpg

But when I pasted the URL into a new browser window and navigated to it, I saw this message:

```
{
    errors: [
        {
            message: "PersistedQueryNotFound",
            extensions: {
                code: "PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What must I do to directly navigate to that URL and see the same JSON data I saw in my browser's developer's console?

Answer (score 1):

The URL cannot be opened directly in a browser because it uses several headers in the request. If you can examine the request clearly you will some keys such as `x-airbnb-api-key`.